# Kubernetes - Azure Application Gateway Ingress Controller vs Ambassador

Tags: azure, kubernetes, ambassador

I have a Kubernetes cluster (on-premise) with [Ambassador](https://www.getambassador.io/). But now I am planning to move to Azure Kubernetes Service with Azure application gateway ingress controller.

With the Ambassador I can do the following things currently;

- Ingress routing to microservices
- Defines routes in config
- Routes api calls from one namespace to another via k8s service in api
  target namespace
- Checks authentication on all non public routes
- Make request to auth pod (which requests keycloak), to validate token
  in header (or url param for document urls)

I was going through the Azure Application Gateway Ingress Controller documentation, but I am having a hard time understanding what services (or annotations) should I use in the Azure app gateway ingress controller so I can achieve the same (more or less) things I achieve currently with `Ambassador`

For a start, I saw one [annotation](https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/annotations/#example_11) where you can set private IP's for internal services. Like wise, can someone please help me match the resembling Azure App Gateway Ingres controller functionality to the Ambassador's? Is the annotation along enough necessary? Should I use any other tools/addons with AKS to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

these are all of the annotations supported by agic: https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/annotations/

I'm pretty sure you cant check for auth, but you can redirect to keyclock which would handle auth.

everything else you require is done via ingress resource and doesnt need annotations (at least as far as I can tell).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. Could you explain why when you said you can't check for auth? And also what annotation should I use to re-direct authentication to keycloak? Thank you!

Comment: agic cant check auth, thats what I meant. for redirects you can use built-in functionality of ingress. or, perhaps, agw functionality

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. By considering all the points I have mentioned, only thing that `agic` cannot do is checking auth right? Everything else is a possibility?

Comment: first 3 are definitely possible, the latter 2 not sure are possible (might be possible with a creative approach)

Comment: nps, feel free to upvote if you find this helpful :)

Comment: Could you please suggest me a direction on the 4th and 5th points if possible? At least a hunch/tool where I can research on this?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/860 something like this thread